# powerbi how to avoid circular dependency error

Tags: powerbi, dax, circular-dependency

I've tried add calculated column to my table in power bi. Now I have two columns:

```
Num_of_occurence=CALCULATE(COUNT(Loans[ID]))
```

which calculates how may times specific loan occurs in this table

```
Num_of_all_loans=COUNTROWS(Loans)
```

calculation of number of all loans in table. What I've tried to add is calculated column which calculated percentage

```
Percent=DIVIDE([Num_of_occurence];[Num_of_all_loans])
```

The proble is I got circular dependency error. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need calculated Filed rather you need Measure.
Use the same formula but rather than calculated column create Measure and you shall have your result

```
Column = CALCULATE(DIVIDE([No of Occurence];[Num_of_all_loans]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Making a measure solved the problem for it! Thanks.

```
Measure 1 = CALCULATE(VALUES('All Rates_OTM'[SCAC]))
Measure 2 = CALCULATE(VALUES('All Rates_OTM'[SCAC]))
```

---

Comparison calculated column:

```
IsPreferredCarrier = IF('Table 1'[Measure 1] = 'Table 2'[Measure 2], "Yes", "No")
```